Segmentation fault (core dumped) when accessing memory that has been allocated via new()
When trying to check for a value that has been initialized via new(), I can a segmentation fault error.
int main() {
  const char* const *matrix = new(char*);
  std::cout << matrix[0][0]; // segfault here
  return 0;
}

My suggestion is that there should be garbage value, but no segfault.

You are allocating space for a single char* (char pointer) and then treating that as if it was an array, but it is not an array. Just use std::array or std::vector already.

But why does the g++ (C++ compiler allows that)? It gives me no error.

@JesperJuhl I'm pretty sure [0] is allowed on non-array pointers.

@ArtyomGevorgyan Because new returns a pointer to the allocated object, in this case a pointer to char* which is char** - the type of matrix.

You don't get an error because there are no syntax errors in your code. C++ compilers are not required to diagnose semantic errors etc. You need to know and follow all the language rules and avoid undefined behaviour - the compiler is not going to help you check if what you are doing actually makes sense.

@ArtyomGevorgyan You declared matrix as a pointer to char * and allocate one pointer to char (char *), that is correct. But just after you tried to access data from this new allocated pointer which has been not initialised, which is incorrect.

If this is a learning experiment and you must do it that way, then understand there are 2 different allocations required. First you allocate some number of pointers as you have attempted, but need to omit the const qualifier, e.g. char **matrix = new char*[10]; (to allocate 10 rows in matrix. Then you must allocate storage for each char, e.g. for 10 chars per-pointer for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {  matrix[i] = new char[10]; } Now you have matrix simulating a 10x10 2D array. Don't forget to delete[] the storage per-pointer and delete[] matrix at the end to free the pointers.

You allocate new(char*) and assign in to matrix, which makes matrix[0] to not be a segfault because matrix is a valid pointer.
However, matrix[0] is not a valid pointer. It contains a garbage data, so matrix[0][0] tries to get a random memory location, which ends in a segfault.
